# How to recreate shortcut to webstart application?

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

I use the shortcut tag in my appliation's jnlp descriptor to create a desktop link and a menu entry for my application.

If these shortcuts get deleted on the client - how can they be reinstalled **automatically** without user action? Is there a configuration option for the jnlp file?

(btw I'm using java6)

Comment: if someone got a solution, i'm interested too! thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Here is a skeleton of an automatic way (**you need `javaws.jar` in your classpath for this to work**):

```
IntegrationService is = null;
try
{
    is = (IntegrationService) ServiceManager.lookup("javax.jnlp.IntegrationService");
}
catch (UnavailableServiceException use)
{
    // integration service unavailable
}

if (!is.hasDesktopShortcut())
{
    if (!is.requestShortcut(true, true, "Companyapp"))
    {
        // failed to install shortcuts
    }
}
else
{
    // shortcuts already exist
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Please refere this link - http://mindprod.com/jgloss/javawebstart.html

> SUMMARY:If you want JWS to recreate
>   menu and/or desktop shortcuts, delete
>   both the menu item and the desktop
>   icon, then run javaws -viewer on the
>   command line then click the  button to
>   create the shortcuts. If either one
>   exists, javaws.exe won’t create the
>   other. It also might not create them
>   where you were expecting, so look
>   around.

Comment: thanks! this works, BUT: in the described way the user needs to do this manually on the client - it would be better if this could be done automatically, e.g. that during launching from the web, java checks if the shortcuts exists - and if not, installs them!

Answer (score 3):

The [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/javaws.html) for Java6 on javaws show that you can either use the executable to launch an app or to perform maintenance operations they call control options.

Two of those options are:

```
javaws -uninstall <jnlp>
javaws -import [import-options] <jnlp>
```

one of the things you can do is

```
javaws -import -silent -shortcut <jnlp>
```

So if you can run a script that first uninstalls your particular jnlp app and then silently re-imports it and its shortcuts then that would solve your problem. I don't think Java will automatically do this for you.

Note that the documentation says that it has to be a silent installation for the shortcut option to work. Also, I haven't double checked that this actually works myself.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to add a comment on the above solution, in case it saves anyone time.

**IF** your application is installed in the WebStart cache, but the shortcut has been removed (like during a java update, or the user removes) the javaws -import -silent -shortcut  **will NOT** just recreate the shortcut for the application. At least for 1.6.0_u35 and u37.

It seems as though WebStart checks to see if the application is in the cache, if it is, it just exits **WITHOUT** creating the shortcut. Very disappointing...